# How do I only show render when the render has completed in React?

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

Hope this doesn't sound like a stupid question, but all queries I've searched on here and Google ask about only showing the render once fetches/requests have completed.

I want my React app to only show the render once the render has completed, including the CSS. At the moment, in a fraction of a second, you can see the page being built - in under a split second, but still it's not a fluid flow for the UX. Is there a way to only load the page once the render (including the CSS) is all done? I don't want to do a setTimeout with a loading page as that is very clunky.

Many thanks in advance

Code below:

```js
import React, { useEffect, useContext } from 'react';
import { NavLink } from 'react-router-dom';
import axios from 'axios';
import '../../styles/MleaveReqUpper.css';
// import '../../styles/leaveRequests.css';
import leftArrow from '../../img/general/leftArrow.svg';
import teamsGrad from '../../img/general/teamsGrad.png';
import returnBack from '../../img/general/returnBack.svg';
import cog from '../../img/general/cog.svg';
import checklist from '../../img/general/checklist.svg';
import { DataContext } from '../../contexts/DataContext';

import $ from 'jquery';
import requestsSelected from '../../img/mFooter/requestsSelected.svg';

const MLeaveReqUpperLinks = () => {
  const { teamAllows, toggleTeamAllows } = useContext(DataContext);

  const navBlue = () => {
    $('.f3').attr('src', requestsSelected);
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    axios.get('db.json').then();
  });



  // render
  return (
    <div className='leaveReqUpperContainer'>

      <img className='teamGradientOut' src={teamsGrad} />

      <NavLink to='/requests'>
        <div
          className='backGroup'
          onClick={() => {
            navBlue();
            if (teamAllows) {
              toggleTeamAllows(false);
            }
          }}
        >
          <img
            className='returnBack'
            src={returnBack}
            alt='Back to My Requests'
          />
        </div>
      </NavLink>

      <h3 className='TeamRequests'>Team Requests</h3>

      <div className='iconsM'>
        <NavLink to='team-allowances'>
          <img
            onClick={() => {
              toggleTeamAllows();
            }}
            className={`checklist ${!!teamAllows ? 'iconSelected' : ''}`}
            src={checklist}
            alt='Allowances'
          />
        </NavLink>
        <img className='cog' src={cog} alt='Settings' />
      </div>

      <div className='teamsXbar'>
        <div className='teamsInnerContainer'>
          <div className='teamMenuHolder'>
            <p className='teamName teamSel '>All Staff</p>
          </div>
          <div className='teamMenuHolder'>
            <p className='teamName'>Brewery</p>
          </div>
          <div className='teamMenuHolder'>
            <p className='teamName'>Sales</p>
          </div>
          <div className='teamMenuHolder'>
            <p className='teamName'>Finance</p>
          </div>
          <div className='teamMenuHolder'>
            <p className='teamName'>Operations</p>
          </div>
          <div className='teamMenuHolder'>
            <p className='teamName'>Marketing</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default MLeaveReqUpperLinks;
```

Comment: Are you conditionally rendering pars of your UI? You can always conditionally render the entire page when you have ***all*** the data you need to render an entire page at once. Please include a [Minimal, Complete, and Reproducible](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) code example so it's clearer what you mean.

Comment: @drewReese yes I am using one or two conditional renders in there - by means of classNames. How would I update the state to know when the whole thing has rendered? Or is it manual, with perhaps callbacks after every load? Also, i pasted my code - thanks for the tip.

Comment: It would basically be a conjunction of *all* your conditionals in a single check versus sprinkled throughout the render function.

Comment: Why are you using jQuery? `$('.f3').attr('src', requestsSelected)` this will probably cause issues you are seeing I'm guessing.

Comment: Only "state" I see is `teamAllows`, you could just `return teamAllows ? (/* all your JSX */) : null;` to hide the entire component until `teamAllows` is truthy. @Joe the jquery use looks to just be setting the src attribute on some img tag with id `f3`.

Comment: Thanks all. I have scrapped the jQuery as I have read it clashes with the DOM manipulation done by React. I've removed the jQuery and used Drew's conditional and it appears to be better, but i do think there's some browser render still flicking (although very quickly, and certainly quicker this time). Thanks for the help.

Comment: If you want to, and can, please try to create a codesandbox that reproduces the issue to share here. In the meantime, have you tested your code in other browsers, other devices'/machines' browsers, etc... does it still reproduce there as well?

Answer (score 1):

You can use a loading state variable

```
const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(false);

useEffect(() => {
  setIsLoading(true);
  axios.get('db.json').then(res=>setIsLoading(false););
});

return isLoading ? null : <div>All your view</div>
```